# Keeping track of our stats

Tags: discussion, feature-request, statistics

Moderators have a view of the site's statistics, but they cannot share the specifics. So, I'm starting this post to keep track of the evolution of our statistics over time. Please feel free to update it every now and then:

```
  Date           Qs/day     Visits/day     A. ratio     Total users    Avid users
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2012-07-04     4.6        448
  2012-10-04     4.0        700
  2012-11-12     4.0        994            2.5          1986
  2012-11-19     3.7       1005            2.6          2048           184
  2012-11-28     5.2       1068            2.6          2123           190
  2012-12-03     5.7       1068            2.6          2154           192
  2012-12-10     3.9       1093            2.6          2194           195
  2012-12-17     4.4       1109            2.5          2275           200
  2013-01-01     3.1        765            2.6          2361           207
  2013-01-07     3.5        772            2.6          2402           209
  2013-01-14     4.9       1056            2.6          2471           212
  2013-01-21     6.1       1308            2.6          2549           216
  2013-01-28     6.0       1392            2.6          2640           222
  2013-02-04     6.1       1397            2.7          2786           235
  2013-02-11     6.1       1452            2.7          2835           237
  2013-02-18     5.5       1312            2.7          2903           240
  2013-02-25     4.5       1361            2.7          2978           244
  2013-03-04     4.9       1449            2.7          3101           248
  2013-03-11     6.2       1533            2.7          3173           254
  2013-03-18     6.5       1557            2.7          3240           262
  2013-03-26     5.8       1653            2.7          3324           271
  2013-04-02     5.0       1651            2.7          3486           283
  2013-04-08     5.7       1621            2.7          3545           288
  2013-04-15     6.0       1572            2.7          3612           292
  2013-04-22     6.6       1497            2.7          3684           293
  2013-04-29     6.9       1485            2.7          3749           296
  2013-05-14     4.5       1458            2.7          3861           303
  2013-06-10     5.7       2008            2.7          4142           318
  2013-06-18     4.6       2008            2.7          4198           322
  2013-07-15     5.4       2139            2.7          4465           329
  2013-07-29     6.8       2392            2.7          4656           339
  2013-08-19     6.6       2503            2.7          4914           351
  2013-08-26     7.1       2739            2.7          5049           356
  2013-09-09     7.0       3127            2.7          5188           369
  2013-09-17     7.6       3251            2.7          5279           372
  2013-09-23     7.8       3256            2.7          5341           372
  2013-09-30     6.9       3350            2.7          5414           390
  2013-10-07     6.9       3568            2.6          5504           392
  2013-10-14     7.4       3572            2.6          5595           401
  2013-10-21     6.9       3863            2.6          5666           408
  2013-10-28     6.1       3954            2.6          5754           411
  2013-11-04     5.9       4229            2.6          5851           419
  2013-11-12     6.5       4408            2.6          5951           425
  2013-11-19     7.1       4711            2.6          6082           430
  2013-11-25     7.9       4938            2.6          6180           438
  2013-12-02     6.0       4452            2.6          6284           443
  2014-01-10     9.5       3932            2.6          7118           473
  2014-01-17    10.3       6332            2.6          7408           487
  2014-01-24     9.3       6409            2.6          7603           493
  2014-01-31     9.3       6264            2.6          7832           501
  2014-02-07    10.9       7012            2.6          8109           507
  2014-02-14    11.9       7351            2.6          8308           518
  2014-03-14    10.9       8138            2.6          9418           565
```

I use the [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia) page as source for those stats.

---

Graphs of the visits/day, number of users, and questions per day:

[image]

And here's the Quantcast estimate of site traffic, with a sparkline for the last 6 months, mean number of visitors per month, and highest and lowest daily visitor count in the last 6 months:
[image]

Comment: Why do we have historical Qs/day and Visits/day, but not A. ratio and Total users?

Comment: @gerrit because I found those mentioned in a chat room message and in a meta post… but only questions and visits were quoted.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the answers/day has been constant at 2.5 for a long time.

Comment: I think more people need to get involved. As of now its just a site to get your questions answered by 'a very select few' people. Not everyone answers questions here. Its typically 5-10% of the entire set of people who answer the questions. This is unlike other SE sites.

Comment: @Naresh it is not that select for a beta site. We have 24 users with 2000+ rep which suggests that at least 24 people are/were regularly answering questions.

Comment: @F'x many thanks for your work in keeping this updated. It's great to see our progress

Comment: We seem to be in the green for everything except Q/day which is "okay". Does that mean we can graduate from beta soon?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to add the tag "feature request". I hope that it is not going to far. I am surprised that these data aren't already available on area51.

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev - See [this answer](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/321/73) for some clarity on getting out of beta.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub - Unfortunately, that tag isn't going to get any attention here. Try posting it on the main [SO meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), which also serves as a general meta for questions like this for all the stack exchange sites. If you haven't posted there before, though, do note that they can be a bit rough on the newbies; they don't hesitate to downvote over there. Take it in stride :)

Comment: Surprising how the traffic *increases* during summer.

Comment: @gerrit I wondered about that… maybe because there is less work to do? :)

Comment: how we keep tracking our stat after graduation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is now obsolete, a historic artefact from the beta

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to make the post overlong, so I paste here the Mathematica code used to make the graphs from the raw data (multiline string stored pasted in variable `s`):

```
t = StringSplit /@ StringSplit[s, "\n"];
time = ToExpression@StringSplit[#, "-"] & /@ t[[All, 1]];
values = ToExpression@t[[All, 2 ;;]];
GraphicsColumn[{
  DateListPlot[Riffle[time, values[[All, 2]]]~Partition~2, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
   PlotRange -> {All, {0, Automatic}}, 
   DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "YearShort"}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, "Visits / day"}],
  DateListPlot[Riffle[time[[3 ;;]], values[[3 ;;, 4]]]~Partition~2, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
   PlotRange -> {All, {0, Automatic}}, 
   DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "YearShort"}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, "Users"}],
  DateListPlot[Riffle[time, values[[All, 1]]]~Partition~2, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
   PlotRange -> {All, {0, Automatic}}, 
   DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "YearShort"}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, "Questions / day"}]
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Any news on the stats? It feels like we are getting more traffic these days

Comment: I added in data for today and ran some quick "stats". We are at the highest questions/day ever recorded in the table. The questions per day as a function of time is about equally well fit in terms of SSE by both a 1 degree polynomial and a 1 term exponential, although they obviously make different predictions about our rate of growth. The linear model says the questions/day increases by 2.6 questions/day per year.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub nice! Thanks :)